# Add http://www. in the text if not Exist

Tags: android, android-webview, textview, android-textattributes

How can I know that some text contain "http://www." I want to show domain in Web View. Domain name is written in TextView but there is no restriction to add prefix. If user didn't enter it I have to add and display URL in webview.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do like this

```
String url = textView.getText().toString();
if(!url.startsWith("www.")&& !url.startsWith("http://")){
  url = "www."+url;
}
if(!url.startsWith("http://")){
  url = "http://"+url;
}
```

You can use this url to display content in WebView

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: This approach is a bit simpler than using regex. Anyway, you should also handle the case where the user types `www.domain.com`

Comment: Hey Sebastien,please check answer again

Comment: Hm, this approach is buggy (you may end up with URLs like `www.http://www.domain.com`). Anyway, I think the poster will adjust the code according to his needs.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, please check improved answer

Comment: if(!byte_link.startsWith("www.") ){
                    if (!byte_link.startsWith("http")) {
                        byte_link = "www." + byte_link;
                    }
                }
                if(!byte_link.startsWith("http://")){
                    byte_link = "http"+byte_link;
                }

should be corrected

Answer (score 5):

just modified @silwar answer and add https :

```
 if(!url.startsWith("www.")&& !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
        url = "www."+url;
    }
    if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
        url = "http://"+url;
    }
```

But remember it that sometimes `http://` create security exception in android so we should use `https://`.So for risk-free code, we have to do that like the last checking -

```
 if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
            url = "https://"+url;}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way of checking that the domain name is well formed and contains (or not) a prefix, is using a regular expression.

Check out [Java Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to match regex in Android. It is worth it.

Comment: link is dead (404)

Answer (score 2):

As Sebastien requested, regex is a good option.
You can also get the text from the view, create an URI object

```
Uri uri = Uri.create(view.getText().toString());
```

then with uri.somemethod
You should be able to get everything about an url you want to know.
If the uri fails to create, you generate error messages cause something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would just get the text from the TextView and parse it via startsWith().
If this is false, just add it to the text and use setText() to reasign it.

You might also want to check for other expressions like only "www.". So take a closer look at contains().

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
String a = "http://";
webview.loadUrl(a + url.getText().toString());
```